# Keras won't broadcast-multiply the model output with a mask designed for the entire mini batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, array-broadcasting

I have a data generator that produces batches of input data (`X`) and targets (`Y`), and also a mask (`batch_mask`) to be applied to the model output (the same mask applies to all the datapoint in the batch; there are different masks for different batches and the data generator takes care of doing this).

As a result, the first dimension of `batch_mask` could have shape `1` or `batch_size` (by repeating the same mask along the first dimension `batch_size` times). I was expecting Keras to let me use either, and I wanted to simply create masks having a shape of `1` on the first dimension.

However, when I tried this, I got the error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 128, 1
  y sizes: 128
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

**Why won't Keras broadcast along the first dimension?** It seems like this should not be complicated.

Here's some minimal example code to observe this behavior

```
import tensorflow.keras as tfk
import numpy as np

#######################
# 1. model definition #
#######################

# model parameters
nfeatures_in = 6
target_size = 8

# model inputs
input = tfk.layers.Input(nfeatures_in)
input_mask = tfk.layers.Input(target_size)

# model graph
out = tfk.layers.Dense(target_size)(input)
out_masked = tfk.layers.Multiply()((out,input_mask)) # multiply all model outputs in the batch by the same mask
model = tfk.Model(inputs=(input, input_mask), outputs=out_masked)

##########################
# 2. dummy data creation #
##########################

batch_size = 32

# create masks the batch
zeros_vector = np.zeros((1,target_size)) # "batch_size"==1
zeros_vector[0,:6] = 1
batch_mask = zeros_vector

# dummy data creation
X = np.random.randn(batch_size, 6)
Y = np.random.randn(batch_size, target_size)*batch_mask # the target is masked by design in each batch


############################
# 3. compile model and fit #
############################

model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss="mse")
model.fit((X, batch_mask),Y, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I know I could make this work by either:

- repeating the mask to make the first dimension of `batch_mask` be the size of the first dimension of `X` (instead of 1).
- using pure tensorflow (but I feel like broadcasting along the batch dimension should not be a problem for Keras).

**How can I make this work with Keras?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to (properly) use a `DataGenerator`.

See the gist with the working code: https://gist.github.com/iranroman/2aaecf5b5621051df6b1b6b5394e5ef3

Thank you [@Marco Cerliani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10375049/marco-cerliani) for the discussion that led to figuring out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `IdentityLayer` which receives as an external input parameter the `batch_mask` and returns it as a tensor.

```
class IdentityLayer(tfk.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, my_mask, **kwargs):
        super(IdentityLayer, self).__init__()
        self.my_mask = my_mask
    def call(self, _):
        my_mask = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.my_mask, dtype=tf.float32)
        return my_mask
    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "my_mask": self.my_mask,
        })
        return config
```

The usage of `IdentityLayer` in a model is straightforward:

```
# model inputs
input = tfk.layers.Input(nfeatures_in)
input_mask = IdentityLayer(batch_mask)(input) 

# model graph
out = tfk.layers.Dense(target_size)(input)
out_masked = tfk.layers.Multiply()((out,input_mask)) 
model = tfk.Model(inputs=input, outputs=out_masked)
```

Where `batch_mask` is a numpy array created as you reported:

```
zeros_vector = np.zeros((1,target_size)) # "batch_size"==1
zeros_vector[0,:6] = 1
batch_mask = zeros_vector
```